# what is the reason for wso2 api manger 3.2.0 'JMSListener Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started' error?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I start WSO2 API Manager (3.2.0), I face this error. What is the solution?

```
[2022-12-05 16:00:02,145] ERROR - JMSListener Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2022-12-05 16:00:02,144] ERROR - JMSListener Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2022-12-05 16:00:02,143] ERROR - JMSListener Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2022-12-05 16:00:02,150] ERROR - JMSListener Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2022-12-05 16:00:02,149] ERROR - JMSListener Unable to continue server startup as it seems the JMS Provider is not yet started. Please start the JMS provider now.
[2022-12-05 16:00:02,158] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 1 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 20 seconds
[2022-12-05 16:00:02,159] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 1 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 20 seconds
[2022-12-05 16:00:02,174] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 1 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 20 seconds
[2022-12-05 16:00:02,175] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 1 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 20 seconds
[2022-12-05 16:00:02,163] ERROR - JMSListener Connection attempt : 1 for JMS Provider failed. Next retry in 20 seconds
```

Comment: Please check whether 5672 port is available in your machine.

Comment: this port is open